# Should a bushing or sealant be used when bolting a gun safe to the cab floor?

Tags: nissan, bushing, titan, fluid

The Nissan Titan quad cab has a rear seat fold up which when moved up shows a visible compartment for storage.  I would like to remove this plastic compartment and install a custom gun safe but I am unsure how to properly secure it to the cab.  To prevent leakage or any weather related material coming through the holes on the bottom of the cab what is the strongest solution I should use for securing the safe that would prevent it from allowing fluid to leak in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is going to be a permanent installation, I'd go about doing two things:

1. At every mounting bolt, put a grommet/bushing between the safe and the floor of the truck. This will provide a bit of cushioning for the safe to ride on, keeping the safe up off of the floor itself. This in turn will help prevent rattles down the road.
2. Once the mounting bolts are in place, coat the exposed bolt heads with some type of sealant. This will help prevent the leakage you're worried about, plus it will prevent rusting/deterioration of the bolts over the long haul. It will also prevent the water seepage into the cab. Just ensure you cover the entire area with the sealant.

Comment: Presumably you will have drill holes through the floor pan.  I'd spray the exposed bolts/nuts with a layer of primer and then undercoating.

Comment: @Blackbeagle - Good point. Could even use POR15 in such a case. One application and good protection.

Comment: Why not edit that into the answer?